# Exported UWP template is not running

Tags: uwp, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I have created a UWP blank app in VS2017 and ran it. Its working perfectly.

[image]

It has x86 and Local Machine in the bar.

Then I export it by going to Project->Export Template and include the template in my VSIX. Then I installed the VSIX. Then created a project with that template. Now that project couldn't run.

[image]

It has ARM and Device in the bar. So that I cannot run the project. If I run the project, the below error is coming.

[image]

If I change to x86 manually, the project is running fine. What is the problem here? How can I set to x86 by default to my template. I have checked the project and solution files. There is no entry is available for this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. There is an entry in .vstemplate file itself to set the default configuration like below.

```
<TemplateContent PreferedSolutionConfiguration="Debug|x86">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to **Start IpOverUsbSvc** in Services. You can follow the below steps

#### Method 1:

1. Search **Services** and Open it
2. Find **Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)**
3. **Right click** it
4. Select **Start**

#### Method 2:

1. Open **PowerShell** in Admin mode
2. Run **`start-service IpOverUsbSvc`**

Comment: Thanks. It will clear the error right? But I want to set the x86 or Any CPU as configuration by default. How to do this?

Comment: If you change it in the toolbar then it would normally set it as Default. But you can manually set by following these steps: **Right Click Project** in Solution Explorer => Select **Properties** => **Build** Tab => Set your CPU Configuration in **Platform Target** => **Save** it before closing the tab.

Comment: Thanks. I know this method. But I want to set this automatically by editing .csproj file or any other else.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: I use the project as a template in my Visual Studio extension. I cannot say my customers to do it by going to Solution Explorer. It should be as default. :(

Comment: I don't know any way to change CPU configuration by editing .csproj. Maybe you want to ask a new question on StackOverflow because this post is regarding IpOverUsbSvc issue.

Comment: Also if this answer helps to solve IpOverUsbSvc issue then consider Mark as Answer